# Issues checking if folder exists

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I have the following C# code that creates a folder:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(strCreatePath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(strCreatePath);
}
```

It works, except if I have a folder as such: `C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop` the `Directory.Exists` returns `false`, which is not true, but then `Directory.CreateDirectory` throws an exception: `Access to the path 'C:\\Users\\UserName\\Desktop' is denied.`.

Any idea how to prevent that apart from catching such exception, which I prefer to avoid?

Comment: Existence and permission to write are two separate things.

Comment: You can use `Directory.CreateDirectory` alone which checks if the Dicrectory exists. Then you also avoid race conditions.

Comment: is `UserName` your username you are logged in with or another users account, and are you and adminitrator and your application running with admin rights?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: `Directory.CreateDirectory` will raise `access denied` exception, and that's what I"m trying to avoid.

Comment: @c00000fd - You can potentially get this exception no matter what. Even if you do check the permissions before hand, it could still change in between when you checked and attempt to access it. You need to handle this exception if it is a possibility.

Comment: Remove the `Directory.Exists` and handle the exceptions which are entirely to be expected. That said, you should never be creating a directory of that name

Answer (score 1):

[According to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx):

> If you do not have at a minimum read-only permission to the directory,
>   the Exists method will return false.

So the behavior you are seeing is expected. This is a legitimate exception that can happen even if you do check for permissions, so your best bet is to simply handle the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You should check first if the directory is [`ReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) or not:

```
bool isReadOnly = ((File.GetAttributes(strCreatePath) & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
if(!isReadOnly)
{
    try
    {
         Directory.CreateDirectory(strCreatePath);
    } catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException unauthEx)
    {
        // still the same eception ?!
        Console.Write(unauthEx.ToString());
    }
    catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
    {
        Console.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone. Here's how I was able to handle it without throwing unnecessary exceptions:

```
[DllImportAttribute("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CreateDirectory(string lpPathName, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes);

void createFolder(string strCreatePath)
{
    if (!CreateDirectory(strCreate, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        int nOSError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (nOSError != 183)        //ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS
        {
            //Error
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(nOSError);
        }
    }
}
```